# Setting a Fortran integer array with character string in C++

Tags: c++, fortran, character

Because of project limitations, I need to pass a character string from a C++ routine to a Fortran routine via a shared common block as a Fortran `integer*1(255)` array.

The representation of the array in the C++ routine is set by a project program as:

```
shared data base definition:
extern __CTYPE__ __declspec (dllimport) struct global_xx globalxx;
```

The array of interest in the global database is defined as:

```
#define routine_file(x1) (*(unsigned char *)(globalxx.b + ((x1)-x)*1))
```

Further in the C++ routine I need to assign a file name to this variable:

```
routine_file == "long file name with directory structure";
```

Later in a Fortran routine, the variable will come in as:

```
  COMMON/GLOBALxx/GLBxx(0:bignum)
  CHARACTER*1 GLBxx
  INTEGER*1 routine_file(255)
  EQUIVALENCE (routine_file,GLBxx(num in bignum))
```

i know how to handle the variables in fortran. i would appreciate assistance in loading the variable routine_file in the c++ portion of the code.

thank you

Comment: Help to do what?  I'm afraid I can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the  Welcome [tour] and see [ask]. Is there any problem with your approach? Error messages? Wrong results? Please show us your details like the full output.

Comment: So, you told us the structures you're trying to play with, but what have you tried?  How did your attempt deviate from expected behavior?  We need more information before we can be of any help.

Comment: so I have two additional variables path and filename that I have added to the C++ routine.
to load the path+filename into the variable I have added the following:




strcat(routine_file, path):
strcat(routine_file, filename);



which results in routine_file undeclared identifier

Comment: Please edit your question with the details such as your error messages. Show them step by step and show the **complete** error output as far as reasonably possible. Please try to use CAPITAL letters when you begin a sentence.

Comment: The short question is:::::::   I need to know how to load a character string into the variable routine_file that is defined above.